# How to model this shape

Tags: modeling

What is a good way to model this kind of shape?

[image]

Comment: Consider marking this shape with something more visible. It took me a while to get what do you want by "this shape".

Comment: Please be more specific when asking questions. Please avoid Vague titles like "how do I do this?"

Comment: Yeah you're right, I'll be sure to making it more visible in future question. I figured it out though,

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by beveling a cube, deleting the top and right hand side and extruding it. Sometimes I just get stuck on the simple things

Sorry for the poor question

[image]